# How much does a minecraft bedrocks server affect internet speed?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, performance, hosting, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I share a internet router with my neighbors and they run a `minecraft : bedrock edition` server that is on all the time even when they're not at online. I assume they run it on a raspberry PI or a similar device. How much does this affect internet performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won’t affect internet at all. I have a Minecraft server I run 24/7 and it has no affect on my internet for the rest of the household.